# Как использовать set_footer у embed в библиотеке discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, синтаксис

Не могу понять, как правильно использовать у **Embed** сообщения **set_footer**.

Код:

```
async def findteam(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    global teamList
    
    if len(teamList) > 0:
        open_teamList = "\n\n".join(teamList)
        
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = "Список игроков:",
            description = open_teamList,
            set_footer ="Список очистится ",
            timestamp = futureTime,
            colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(170, 110, 0))
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
        
    else:
        await ctx.send("Список пуст!")
```

Подскажите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

перед await ctx.send напиши

`embed.set_footer()`